# Rename a file with the previous month using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I'd like to rename a file with the previous month + current year using a batch script.  Please help!

For example: rename c:\Example.txt Example_MMYY.txt

Where MM = previous month and YY = current year or Example_0718.txt

Comment: what if the month is 01 - the previous month should be 12 and the year also should be changed?

Comment: Correct!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 :prevmonthren
setlocal

::argument value
::set "file=%~f1"

::hardcoded value
set "file=testfile.txt"

for %%# in ("%file%") do (
    set "ext=%%~x#"
    set "nam=%%~n#"
)

for /f %%# in ('wMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get /Format:value') do @for /f %%@ in ("%%#") do @set %%@


set /a prev_month=month-1
if %prev_month% lss 10 set "prev_month=0%prev_month%"
if %month%==1 (
    set "prev_month=12"
    set /a year=year-1
)
set year=%year:~2%
ren %file% %nam%_%prev_month%%year%%ext%


endlocal
```

you can use hardcoded value for the file location or to uncomment the first line where the file location is set (and comment the second) in order to use command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be solved in a very simple way:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=/" %%m in ("%date%") do (
   set /A "MM=1%%m-1, YY=%%n-!(MM-100), MM+=12*!(MM-100)"
)

ren Example.txt Example_%MM:~-2%%YY:~-2%.txt
```

This method assume that the format of `%date%` variable is `MM/DD/YYYY`. If is not, just change the numbers in the `"tokens=1,3"` option.

Comment: Received the following error...

Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).
Access is denied.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @tsabsuav, the `date` variable is region dependent, so we would need to know what the format of the `date` variable is to adjust the `tokens` and `delims` for the `FOR` command.  I am going to assume you need this: `"tokens=2,4 delims=/ "`

Comment: As I said in the answer, the method assume that the format of `%date%` variable is `MM/DD/YYYY`. If you show us the output of `echo %date%` I could fix the code accordingly...

Comment: @Aacini  Thanks buddy! your updated code works perfectly!  Sorry I don't know how to post the updated code here, but your suggestions above worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with calling out to Powershell to get the date you can simplify the code.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%G in (`powershell "(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMyy')"`) do set "mmyy=%%G"
rename Example.txt Example_%mmyy%.txt
```

Comment: @tsabsuav Saying it didn't work really doesn't help me help you.  You would need to tell me the error you received.

Comment: @tsabsuav, I found the error.  I was missing a percent symbol with the `FOR` meta-variable.  I had been testing from the cmd prompt.  When using the `FOR` command from the cmd prompt you only use one percent symbol. You have to double them in a batch file.  I forgot to double the percent symbol in the `SET` command.